# Add server into Active Directory domain

Tags: active-directory, window

Suppose I have a window 2016 server in site A and create AD user and group, we will install a new server in site B and we want the new server sync user from original AD.

I currently stuck for the case, I dont know how to handle the connection between the 2 server, as they are in seperate site and network.

Comment: You will have to have a connection between both AD servers and setup a forest.

Comment: Are you asking about adding a new _domain controller_, or just a member server where users can log in?

Comment: My only requirement is that I can access AD user list in the new install server.

Comment: The root cause of the case is there is a program in the new server which based on AD user list to authenticate user access, so I have to sync AD user between the server

Comment: You will have to create a connection between the two sites. A VPN connection is the most commonly used type of connection. Assuming both sites have an internet connection, then both sites will have a firewall/router setup as a gateway. A good (business type) router will allow you to create this site to site vpn connection. There are other possibilities, you could have VPN servers inside each location, and setup a connection between them. Possibly  other solutions. But you need to establish a connection between the to locations and VPN router to router is the method I always use.